# Modularizing nightmare and passing the nightmare instance

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web-scraping, yield, nightmare

Im trying to extract data from a website and i want to loop after like 10 minutes to see if the data has changed. I thought packing my functions in modules is a good idea, but now im stuck in getting my current nightmare instance from the login module to the data module.

start.js

```
var config = require('./config.json');
var login = require('./functions/login.js');
var data = require('./functions/data.js');
var vo = require('vo');

var Nightmare = require('nightmare'),
 nightmare = new Nightmare({
    show: config.nightmare.show,
    typeInterval: config.nightmare.typeInterval,
    webPreferences: {
      images: config.nightmare.images,
    }
  });

vo(login.login)(nightmare, function (err, result) {
  if (!result) return;
  console.log('Logged in as ' + config.user.username)
  vo(data.getData)(nightmare, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
  })  
})
```

login.js

```
var config = require('../config.json');
var Nightmare = require('nightmare')

function* login(nightmare) {
    return yield nightmare
        .goto('http://example.com/')
        .click('.gogo').wait(2500)
        .insert('.whsOnd', config.user.username)
        .click('.RveJvd').wait(2500)
        .insert('.whsOnd', config.user.password)
        .click('.RveJvd').wait(4000)
        .then(() => {
            return true;
        })        
}
//login works 

module.exports = {
    login: login
}
```

data.js

```
var config = require('../config.json');
var Nightmare = require('nightmare')

function* getData(nightmare) {
    console.log('Getting data ...' + nightmare)
    return yield nightmare        
        .click('.index_menu').wait(1000)
        .evaluate(()=>{
          // do stuff
        })                       
        .then((result) => {
            return result;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Failure: ' + error)
        })
}

module.exports = {
    getData: getData
}
```

My evaluate functions are working the only problem is, that even though nightmare isnt undefinded in data.js, for example the path is.

Comment: I did not know about VO, reading about it a bit it seems your usage is completely wrong...

Comment: Then how do i use it?

Comment: can't say really... But just have a look at the readme... First thing is they use .then with only a callback, while you aren't using then, calling the return value as a function directly, with 2 parameters... This could be a way to do it, I just don't think it's the usual way.

Comment: Yeah even if its not the usual way. It is working

Answer (score 0):

You created separate nightmare instances. They don't share the same cookie session, thus your login session does't reflect in the getdata instance. you can try passing the cookie from the login instance and set it in the getdata instance.

login.js

```
         nightmare
            .goto('http://example.com/')
            .click('.gogo').wait(2500)
            .insert('.whsOnd', config.user.username)
            .click('.RveJvd').wait(2500)
            .insert('.whsOnd', config.user.password)
            .click('.RveJvd').wait(4000)
            .cookies.get()
            .then((cookie) => {
                return cookie; // pass this cookie to getdata
            })
```

data.js

```
nightmare 
   .cookies.set(cookies) //set cookies from login session
   .click('.index_menu').wait(1000)
   .evaluate(()=>{
              // do stuff
            })                       
    .then((result) => {
             return result;
          })
    .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Failure: ' + error)
          })
    }
```